# OpenGL VBO data seems to get corrupted

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I've uploaded vertices, colors, normals, and texture coordinates into a single VBO, which is associated with a VAO.  I also have an EBO associated with the same VAO that stores indices.  I am also using SDL and OpenGL 3.3 (Core Profile context, which is set using SDL).

At first, my model seems to render fine.  Then after maybe 8 or so seconds, it looks like the data gets corrupted.

Here is a video: https://youtu.be/eEiH3EFTPFk

Every frame I am pulling the data out of OpenGL (using `glGetNamedBufferSubData`) and comparing to what it should be, and everything seems to check out.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here?  I appreciate any insight you guys might be able to provide.

Here is my code for loading the model data:

```
struct Vbo
{
    GLuint id;
};

struct Ebo
{
    GLuint id;
    GLenum mode;
    GLsizei count;
    GLenum type;
};

struct Vao
{
    GLuint id;
    Vbo vbo[4];
    Ebo ebo;
};

// ...

MeshId GraphicsEngine::createStaticMesh(
    std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices,
    std::vector<glm::detail::uint32> indices,
    std::vector<glm::vec4> colors,
    std::vector<glm::vec3> normals,
    std::vector<glm::vec2> textureCoordinates
)
{
    Vao vao;

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao.id);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vao.vbo[0].id);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vao.ebo.id);

    auto size = vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3);
    size += colors.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4);
    size += normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3);
    size += textureCoordinates.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2);

    glBindVertexArray(vao.id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao.vbo[0].id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    auto offset = 0;
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    offset += vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, colors.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4), &colors[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(offset));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    offset += colors.size() * sizeof(glm::vec4);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &normals[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(offset));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    offset += normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, offset, textureCoordinates.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &textureCoordinates[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(3, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLvoid*)(offset));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(3);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vao.ebo.id);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(glm::detail::uint32), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    vao.ebo.count = indices.size();
    vao.ebo.mode = GL_TRIANGLES;
    vao.ebo.type =  GL_UNSIGNED_INT;

    vertexArrayObjects_.push_back(vao);
    auto index = vertexArrayObjects_.size() - 1;

    return MeshId(index);
}
```

Here is my code that does the rendering:

```
// Setup camera
const glm::quat temp = glm::conjugate(camera_.orientation);

view_ = glm::mat4_cast(temp);
view_ = glm::translate(view_, glm::vec3(-camera_.position.x, -camera_.position.y, -camera_.position.z));

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram_);

const int modelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "modelMatrix");
const int pvmMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "pvmMatrix");
const int normalMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram_, "normalMatrix");

glm::detail::uint32 i = 0;  
for ( const auto& r : renderables_ )
{
    const auto& graphicsData = graphicsData_[i];

    glm::mat4 newModel = glm::translate(model_, graphicsData.position);
    newModel = newModel * glm::mat4_cast( graphicsData.orientation );
    newModel = glm::scale(newModel, graphicsData.scale);

    // Send uniform variable values to the shader       
    const glm::mat4 pvmMatrix(projection_ * view_ * newModel);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(pvmMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &pvmMatrix[0][0]);

    glm::mat3 normalMatrix = glm::inverse(glm::transpose(glm::mat3(view_ * newModel)));
    glUniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &normalMatrix[0][0]);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &newModel[0][0]);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, r.texture.id);
    glBindVertexArray(r.vao.id);
    glDrawElements(r.vao.ebo.mode, r.vao.ebo.count, r.vao.ebo.type, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    i++;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec4 ourColor;
in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D ourTexture;

void main()
{
    color = texture(ourTexture, texCoord);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat4 pvmMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec2 textureCoordinate;

out vec4 ourColor;
out vec2 texCoord;

void main()
{
    //gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pvmMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    ourColor = color;
    texCoord = textureCoordinate;
}
```

Comment: Is glGetError() giving you anything?

Comment: It looks like you state is corrupted, not VBO data. Try to enable GL_DEPTH_TEST before rendering.

Comment: It almost seems like your Depthbuffer is getting messed up... Could you filter out all the calls you make that interact with the DB and check them?

Comment: Thanks @MichaelNastenko, that was it! If you want to add an answer I will accept it!  I added `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` before my rendering code and it seems to fix it.  I originally enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST` after I setup my OpenGL Context, but apparently that didn't seem to work - do you need to enable this every time you render?

Comment: @Jarrett Well, AFAIK it should be consistent. Are you sure you don't change it anywhere else?

Comment: `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` shouldn't be disabled implicitly by anything; are you sure you were calling it after your context was set up? (Also disabling the depth buffer is not a "corrupted state"; it's perfectly valid)

Comment: Did a quick grep through my code, and I only enable it once and don't change it after that.  I wonder if SDL is modifying it somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @MichaelNastenkos comment about,  I added `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);` before my rendering code and it seems to fix it.